# SpringData MongoDB Aggregation Projection exclude

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to exclude using project the field which is (necessary). I'm strugging with this problem quite long time. I can exclude other(outside of spec) field but It's not possible to exclude field in spec field which include necessary.

I expected when I request with spec_id:

```
[
    {
        "spec": {
            "spec_id": "5",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "material": "plastic",
            "size": "L"
        }
    }
]
```

but it returns

```
[
    {
        "spec": {
            "spec_id": "5",
            "parent_id": "2",
            "necessary": {
                "unit": "20X20",
                "dateOfManufacture": "2020",
                "madeIn": "KNOWN",
                "producer": "KNOWN",
                "importer": "KNOWN",
                "productionLocation": "KNOWN"
            },
            "material": "plastic",
            "size": "L"
        }
    }
]
```

I have method here

```
public List<UnwindInventory> selectSpecWithoutNecessary(String spec_id) {
        UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("spec");
        ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project().andExclude("name", "spec.necessary");
        MatchOperation match = Aggregation.
                match(Criteria.where("spec._id").is(spec_id));
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(unwindOperation, match, project);

        return mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, Inventory.class, UnwindInventory.class).getMappedResults();
```

this is dto

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class UnwindInventory {
    private String inventory_id;
    private String name;
    private Spec spec;
    private Necessary necessary;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly!

Comment: I edit my question!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I project manually each of them.